# How can I find the change of coordinate matrix with non-standard basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, coordinate-systems, change-of-basis

I have the following question, which seems straight forward but I have no idea how he obtained is answer. How can I gind the coordinate matrix with a non-standard basis?

Let $\mathcal{g} : \mathcal{P}_2 \rightarrow \mathcal{R^3}$ be a linear transformation defined by: $$g(a + bx + cx^2) = \begin{pmatrix}
a\\ c\\ b \end{pmatrix}$$

Find $[g]_{\mathcal{C}\leftarrow \mathcal{B}}$ where $\mathcal{B} = \{x, 1, x^2 \}$ and $$\mathcal{C} = \Bigg\{ \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 1\\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \Bigg\} $$ are bases for $\mathcal{P}_2$ and $\mathcal{R}^3$ respectively

My work thus far:

$g(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, g(x^2) =  \begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, g(1) = \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$

First get $g(B)$

$b_{3} = a + b + c$

$b_{2} = b + c$

$b_{1} = c$

Thus:

$c = b_{1}$

$b = -b_1 + b_2$

$a = -b_2 + b_3$

Then we have matrix:

$\begin{pmatrix}
0& 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: $\{1+2x+x^2\}$ is **not** a basis for $\mathcal{P}_2$. You meant $\{1,2x,x^2\}$?

Comment: @IvoTerek I edited it.... my bad

Comment: Ok. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you meant $\{1,2x,x^2\}$ instead of $\{1+2x+x^2\}$, the algorithm is simple: compute $g$ at each element of $\mathcal{B}$, write the result as a combination of the elements of $\mathcal{C}$, and put the coefficients in the columns. For example, since $$g(1) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = 1\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}+0\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}+0\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},$$we'll have $$[g]_{\mathcal{C} \leftarrow \mathcal{B}} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & ? & ? \\ 0 & ? & ? \\ 0 & ? & ? \end{pmatrix}.$$Do the same for $g(2x)$ and $g(x^2)$ to fill what is missing.

---

If $\mathcal{B} = \{x,1,x^2\}$ the idea is the same, just paying attention to the order of the vectors in the basis. Again: $$g(x) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}= 0\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}-1\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}+1\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},$$and so $$[g]_{\mathcal{C} \leftarrow \mathcal{B}} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & ? & ? \\ -1 & ? & ? \\ 1 & ? & ? \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: I changed the question... I don't know where I got that other value

Comment: Where does the $-1$ come from and the values you multiply each vector by?

Comment: Write $g(x) = (0,0,1) = a(1,0,0) + b(1,1,0) + c(1,1,1) = (a+b+c,b+c,c)$, set each component in the left side equal to the corresponding one in the right side, and solve the system for $a$, $b$ and $c$. You'll get $a=0$, $b=-1$ and $c=1$. Since this particular system is easy, you can solve it mentally.

Comment: ohhh of course, that makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add additional steps? I'm still not quite following. How exactly do you get $g(x) = (0 0 1)$? This is just a practice question so I am just trying to learn. For $g(x^2) $ I would get $(0,1,0)$ right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Just write $x =1\cdot x+0\cdot 1 + 0\cdot x^2$ and read the coefficients. Similarly for $x^2$.

Comment: I still can't see why you get (0, -1, 1). I understand how but why are you getting this?

Comment: Read the answer again: the algorithm to find $[g]_{\mathcal{C}\leftarrow\mathcal{B}}$ consists in computing $g$ in the elements of $\mathcal{B}$, writing the results as combinations of the elements of $\mathcal{C}$, and **putting the coefficients of the combinations in columns**. Or you're having trouble solving the system?

Comment: I understand the question- But yes I am having trouble understanding and solving  the system as you have...

Comment: Ok. The third component says that $c=1$. The second says that $b+c=0$, whence $b=-1$. The first is $a+b+c=0$, and so $a=0$.

Comment: Okay I added my answer... I tried to formalize the notation a bit. Can you look at it.. I think it is correct accept it is reversed from the matrix you give which I think is ok

Comment: $[g]_{\mathcal{B}\leftarrow\mathcal{C}} $ isn't even defined since ${\rm dom}(g)=\mathcal{P}_2$

Comment: Sorry I mean g(B)